# EXPDP failing because of sys package error

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle19c, expdp

In one of the Oracle 19c databases any expdp or impdp command is failing with the below error

```
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-31637: cannot create job SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 for user SYSTEM
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1145
ORA-04045: errors during recompilation/revalidation of SYS.DBMS_LOGREP_UTIL
ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "SYS.DBMS_LOGREP_UTIL"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 957
```

I can see that the package SYS.DBMS_LOGREP_UTIL is in invalid state with the following errors in the screenshot

[image]

How can I resolve the error and compile the package. The package is wrapped so I cannot see the table which is throwing the looping chain of synonyms error

Comment: You can try recompiling all invalid objects (see here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/recompiling-all-invalid-objects.html), but if that doesn't work you'll need to open a ticket with Oracle Support.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after running catrep.sql and other related sqls in rdbms/admin directory.